# Search user with part of its name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made this script. It returns the username after searching in passwd but the username as to be exactly the same. I want to know if its possible to change it in a way that if the user input is "r" it search for EVERY user with a r in their name instead of searching for the user named r.

```
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]
    then
            echo "Enter your username ( ./user123 user here )"
    else
            nameList=$(getent passwd $@|cut -f1 -d:)
            for i in $nameList;
            do echo $i;
            done
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just `grep` the password database? E.g.

```
 getent passwd | cut -f1 -d: | grep $1
```

Of course, handling multiple names requires more code.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to do this with `getent`, as it effectively hides the backend store for your passwd map, and only searches for entire keys.

But, for the file backend, this would work:

```
$ getent passwd | nawk -F: '$1 ~ /oot/ { print $1 }'
root
```

For *ldap* you would need to learn about ldap queries.